# Is there (already) a way to compare 2 model instances, field for field, to see if they are equal?

Tags: python, django, testing, assert

I'm trying to make an assertion inside one of my tests that the fields from a model have not changed. I know that *philosophically* this is incorrect, but since i control all the variables i need to know about, i just want to check that my DB entry hasn't changed.

I am willing to accept a solution that can transform this into an assertion that some API wasn't called, which is supposed to update models, but i am aware that the API might not be fully documented, so i'd prefer it there was a way to just check if all the field values are equal.

Anyway, i know how to do this, but i'm using django 1.6 and the Model._meta API isn't public yet:

```
def assertFieldsEqual(self, instance1, instance2)
    for field_name in MyModel._meta.get_all_field_names():
        val1 = getattr(instance1, field_name)
        if not isinstance(val1, django.db.models.Field):
            continue  # this excludes managers
        if val1 != getattr(instance2, field_name):
            return False  # or raise assertion error, or whatever
    return True  # or don't do nothing, or whatever
```

So is there a better way?

**[EDIT]**
python 2.7

Comment: Which python version are you using? (2.x or 3.x)

Comment: updated. i'm using djpython 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `django.forms.models.model_to_dict` method and compare the resulting dictionaries with a simple `dict1 == dict2`.

Comment: Although your solution is totally awesome and answered my question, if i wanted to know which are the fields that differ, your solution would require additional code, whereas in the code i provided that would be just another print statememt or smth quick. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: True, though that's basically because this solution is less verbose to begin with. A simple `[name for name in dict1.keys() if dict1[name] != dict2[name]]` would give you all the keys that are different, given that `dict1.keys() == dict2.keys()` because they are the field names.